# Define $Var(XY)$ in terms of $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $Var(X)$, $Var(Y)$ for Independent Random Variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

I currently know: $$Var(XY)=E(X^2Y^2)−[E(XY)]^2$$
$$=E(X^2)E(Y^2)−[E(X)]^2[E(Y)]^2$$
but I am lost where to go from there. I can vaguely see the the formula $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ hidden somewhere, but I do not know how variance out of the equation.

Thanks!

Comment: Solve for $E(X^2)$ in the equation for $Var(X)$ and plug this into your last line.